# correcting doctrine datetime on oracle

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using doctrine for persistence and all of my dates are off. They're being stored as +6 when they should be -6(America/Chicago). I have php and the app server on America/Chicago and can confirm that by the following:

```
php > echo (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d h:m:i a e');
2016-03-02 02:03:47 pm America/Chicago
```

I've created a table in oracle to debug with:

```
  CREATE TABLE "APP"."DATE_TEST" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
    "LOCALTZ" TIMESTAMP (0) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, 
    "NOTLOCALTZ" TIMESTAMP (0) WITH TIME ZONE
   )
```

I have a test entity with the following doctrine mapping:

```
Acme\Project\Domain\Asset\Entity\DateTest:
    type: entity
    table: DATE_TEST
id:
    id:
        type: guid
        generator:
            strategy: none
fields:
    localtz:
        type: datetime
        column: localtz
    notlocaltz:
        type: datetimetz
        column: notlocaltz
```

I execute some code to push the data into the table:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $test = new DateTest();
        $datetime = new \DateTime();
        $test->setLocalTz($datetime);
        $test->setNotLocalTz($datetime);
        $output->writeln($test->getId());
        $output->writeln($datetime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s a'));
        $output->writeln($datetime->getTimezone()->getName());
        $em = $this
            ->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $em->persist($test);
        $em->flush();
        $output->writeln("Test complete.");
    }
```

The following gets outputted

```
de4e5dcd-9fd6-4b5d-b9f0-6db9d1ef0582
2016-03-02 02:51:02 pm
America/Chicago
Test complete.
```

And this is what i see in the database

```
de4e5dcd-9fd6-4b5d-b9f0-6db9d1ef0582    02-MAR-16 08.51.02.000000000 AM 02-MAR-16 02.51.02.000000000 PM +06:00
```

I've got the [oracle session init](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Event.Listeners.OracleSessionInit.html) hooked up.

When I query the database for the current time, it looks correct:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP "NOW" FROM DUAL;
02-MAR-16 02.56.44.342456000 PM -06:00
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Worth checking? Execute this query through php and if you're using a separate client for misc db activities, execute it there: `SELECT DBTIMEZONE, SESSIONTIMEZONE from dual;`

Comment: @Beege executing those from php returns "+00:00" for both queries. That doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tracked it down to the OracleSessionInit class setting the wrong timezone format. The OraclePlatform class does not have a space between the time and the offset while the session format does.

Overriding that format in the container solved my issue.

```
services:
    oci8.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit
        arguments:
            - { NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT: "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM" }
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```

I've opened up an [issue on github](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2332) because I'm pretty sure this is a bug.

Comment: Nice tracing back. I couldn't get my php to return similar (bad) results.